# Add Feeds to Mail.app from the Command Line

Tags: macos, command-line, apple-mail, applescript

Is it possible to add (RSS/Atom) feeds to Apple's Mail.app without using its GUI?

It's possible to subscribe to feeds using Mail.app through Firefox but I don't know how they implemented it (you still have to click on the 'Add' button after Mail.app opened but it comes near to what I want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
open -a Mail feed://example.com/feed.xml
```

Firefox is probably using [-[NSWorkspace openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURLs:withAppBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifiers:).

---

**Another solution**

You can also create RSS feeds by hand. In `~/Library/Mail/RSS/` there is an `.rssmbox` directory for each feed, which contains an XML property list describing the feed's settings.

The only limitation of this method is that changes won't show up in Mail until it's relaunched.

Comment: I accept this answer as there is no better way to do what I want although there still is one manual step to do after firing up this command.